# Resume reading from iostream::cin after Ctrl+Z (EOF)? ("ignore" doesn't work)

Tags: c++, stdin

Why does the outer loop in the following program terminate when we provide ctrl+z for the inner loop only?

```
#include<iostream>
int main()
{
    string s1,s2;

    while(cin >> s1)
    {
        cout<<"In loop1\n";
        while(cin>>s2)
            cout<<"In loop 2\n";
        cin.ignore();
    }
}
```

Comment: I have altered the primary question. I hope it is still inline with your goals (the loops were a secondary effect).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Hitting Ctrl+z (on Windows) closes the standard input stream. Once it's closed, it stays closed. It doesn't magically reopen once the inner loop is finished. There's just no reason why it would.

Comment: He probably knows that `cin.ignore();` clears the EOF state, and is wondering why it can't resume reading after that.

Comment: What input can we provide to terminate the inner loop only?

Answer (score 3):

Ctrl-Z puts cin into an error state so cin.ignore does nowt.
try cin.Clear() instead.