# Unable to enter a character and it results in infinite loop

Tags: c++, loops

The problem is I can't enter the value for 'c',its an infinite loop. I cant see what I did wrong it. I am very new to c++.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class manu
{
    private:
        int sqdno;
        string name,speciality,take;
        ofstream fileip;
        ifstream fileop;
    public:
        manu()
        {
            fileip.open("Manchester United.txt");
            fileop.open("Manchester United.txt");
        }    
    public:
        int input()
        {

            while(cin>>sqdno>>name>>speciality)
            {
              fileip<<sqdno<<' '<<name<<' '<<speciality<<endl;
            }
        }
    public:
        int display()
        {

            fileop>>take;
            while(fileop.good())
            {
                cout<<take<<endl;
                fileop>>take;
            }
        }   
};

int main()
{

    int c;
    manu m;
    cout<<"Enter squad details(press 'Ctrl+z' to exit on input):\n";

    do
    {
    cout<<"Select a choice:"<<endl;
    cout<<"1.Input to file"<<endl;
    cout<<"2.Display from file"<<endl;
    cout<<"3.Exit"<<endl;
    cin>>c;
    switch(c)
    {
        case 1:
            cout<<"Input squad_no,name and speciality of players:";
            m.input();
            break;
        case 2:
            m.display();
            break;
        default:
            cout<<"enter a valid choice";
    }
    }while(c<3);
}
```

Comment: `case '1':` is what you most likely want.

Comment: acess the input function in my class manu

Answer (score 1):

Above code will not compile under visual stdio 8 compiler so because **display** and **input function** needs a return value.

So either change return type to *void* or return some int type of value from function.

I can't enter the value for 'c',its an infinite loop:

You have to modify your switch case if you want to run in infinite loop.

And your function *input* also have bug as it is also an infinite loop.You can take the reference of below code and modify your code accordingly....

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

class manu
{
    private:
        int sqdno;
        string name,speciality,take;
        ofstream fileip;
        ifstream fileop;
    public:
        manu()
        {
            fileip.open("Manchester United.txt");
            fileop.open("Manchester United.txt");
        }    
    public:
        void input()
        {

            cin>>sqdno>>name>>speciality;

            fileip<<sqdno<<' '<<name<<' '<<speciality<<endl;

        }
    public:
        void display()
        {

            fileop>>take;
            while(fileop.good())
            {
                cout<<take<<endl;
                fileop>>take;
            }
        }   
};

int main()
{

    int c;
    manu m;
    cout<<"Enter squad details(press 'Ctrl+z' to exit on input):\n";

    while (1)
    {
        cout<<"Select a choice:"<<endl;
        cout<<"1.Input to file"<<endl;
        cout<<"2.Display from file"<<endl;
        cout<<"3.Exit"<<endl;
        cin>>c;
        switch(c)
        {
            case 1:
                cout<<"Input squad_no,name and speciality of players:";
                m.input();
                break;
            case 2:
                m.display();
                break;
            case 3:
            exit(1);
            default:
                cout<<"enter a valid choice";
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but,I use 'Ctrl+Z' to exit out of the while loop in 'input()',which I believe is the 'end of file' indicator.so,then the while loop must stop right,

Comment: When you enter a 1 on the keyboard, the value stored in c is 49, or `'1'`, not 1.

Comment: Your code works fine,thanks.But I was hoping to do it by entering Ctrl+z as input.

Comment: @RetiredNinja Maybe you are wrong, `c` is a integer here, not a character!

Comment: When you press key 1 for the first time ...so as per your code of *do while* loop it will be an infinite loop as value of c will always be 1 and you and it will not increment ever.If you are satisfy then accept the above answer by clicking the Right button :)

Comment: OUTPUT:-Input squad_no,name and speciality of players:         Select a choice
 1.Input to file"
 2.Display from file
 3.Exit "this goes on forever"

Comment: c is not incremented,but I am entering 'c'(cin>>c) before the switch.

Comment: the statement will be executed only once(first time "do - while loop") it wont ask you to enter every time.

Comment: INPUT:-1 VAN SPECIAL ^Z 'then enter'OUTPUT:-                                                                    Input squad_no,name and speciality of players:                       Select a choice
 1.Input to file"
 2.Display from file
 3.Exit "this goes on forever"

Comment: exit function is used to terminated the main program.Yes you can change the code if you don't want it always to come.

Comment: first time I will enter value for 'c' then it is given to switch then after completing input() in switch it will break out of switch and will encounter the while loop,since c <3 it will goto do,inside do there's a cin>>c; code.I can enter there the value for "c",but i can't.instead an infinite loop is created.

Comment: Hitting Ctrl+z (on Windows) closes the standard input stream. Once it's closed, it stays closed. It doesn't magically reopen once the inner loop is finished. There's just no reason why it would.

Comment: @Kers please refer question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147996/resume-reading-from-iostreamcin-after-ctrlz-eof-ignore-doesnt-work