# Reading from std::cin multiple times -- different behavior on Linux and Mac OS X

Tags: c++, linux, macos, stdin

I want to read some numbers from the standard input, process them, then read the next bunch of numbers.

I came up with the solution to read the `EOF` character in a `char` and clear the eofbit, failbit, and badbit. The following code works on Ubuntu 14.04 with GCC 4.9.2:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    std::vector<double> a;
    std::vector<double>::iterator it;
    double x;
    while(std::cin >> x) {
        a.push_back(x);
    }
    std::cout << "First bunch of numbers:" << std::endl;
    for (it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }

    // get crap out of buffer
    char s;
    std::cin >> s;
    std::cin.clear();

    // go for it again
    while (std::cin >> x) {
        a.push_back(x);
    }
    std::cout << "All the numbers:" << std::endl;
    for (it = a.begin(); it != a.end(); ++it) {
        std::cout << *it << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

So, on Ubuntu I can type `1<Return>2<Return>^D`, get some output, type `3<Return>4<Return>^D`, get more output and the program terminates.

**On Mac OS 10.10** however, using the same GCC version, the **program will not accept the second round of input** but outputs the first sequence of numbers twice after hitting `^D` the first time.

- Why is there inconsistent behavior? Is it possible to work around it?
- What would be the *idiomatic* way to accept input twice?
- In my use case, the first bunch of number may eventually be read from a file or pipeline. How can I ask for additional input interactively also in that scenario.

Comment: Maybe try calling `std::cin.clear()` before using it after sending `EOF` the first time?

Comment: This is console behaviour, not C++ code. In MacOS it is probably closes input stream after sending EOF [like in Windows](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147996/resume-reading-from-iostreamcin-after-ctrlz-eof-ignore-doesnt-work?rq=1)

Answer (score -1):

im not all that familiar but, this guy has a similar question: [Signal EOF in mac osx terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21364313/signal-eof-in-mac-osx-terminal)

> By default, OS X (formerly Mac OS X) terminals recognize EOF when control-D is pressed at the beginning of a line.
>
> In detail, the actual operation is that, when control-D is pressed,
>   all bytes in the terminal’s input buffer are sent to the running
>   process using the terminal. At the start of a line, no bytes are in
>   the buffer, so the process is told there are zero bytes available, and
>   this acts as an EOF indicator.
>
> This procedure doubles as a method of delivering input to the process
>   before the end of a line: The user may type some characters and press
>   control-D, and the characters will be sent to the process immediately,
>   without the usual wait for enter/return to be pressed. After this
>   “send all buffered bytes immediately” operation is performed, no bytes
>   are left in the buffer. So, when control-D is pressed a second time,
>   it is the same as the beginning of a line (no bytes are sent, and the
>   process is given zero bytes), and it acts like an EOF.
>
> You can learn more about terminal behavior by using the command “man 4
>   tty” in Terminal. The default line discipline is termios. You can
>   learn more about the termios line discipline by using the command “man
>   termios”.

Accepted Answer from Eric Postpischil

I dont have OSX to test against, but maybe this explains the behaviour