# How to use cin after using system("pause")?

Tags: c++

For a question, I must use <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd> to end reading parameters for an array.

I search here for this problem and I write this code.

My problem is, after <kbd>Ctrl+Z</kbd>, I can't cin some other variables and array.

```
int main ()
{
    char a[51];
    char b[21];
    int n;
    for(int i=0;i<51;i++)
        a[i]=0;
    int ii=0;
    while(cin >> a[ii]){
        ii++;
    }
        
    system("pause");

    for(int i=0;;i++)
    {
        cin >> b[i]; //problem is here, this line isn't working 
        if(!isalpha(b[i]))
        {
            n=stoi(&b[i]);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;

}
```

Comment: related/dupe: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10147996/resume-reading-from-iostreamcin-after-ctrlz-eof-ignore-doesnt-work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you get an EOF, it gets remembered and won't even try to read anymore by default. Do `std::cin.clear();` after the EOF to make it start trying to read again.